# ¿Por qué obtengo el mensaje de error Segmentation fault (core dumped)?

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

> Escribe un programa, llamado Media, que lea un número indeterminado de
> números enteros por línea de comandos y calcule la media. Por ejemplo:
> ./Media 3 5 1 2
>
> La media es: 2.75
>
> En el caso de detectar que el usuario no ha introducido un número, muestre un error en pantalla y termine.

He escrito una solución para ello pero al ejecutarlo me da el mensaje de error **Segmentation fault (core dumped)** y no sé cuál es el motivo.

Utilizo este código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double media = 0;
    int es_digito;
    int aux;
    es_digito = isdigit(argv[1]);
    for (int i = 1; i < argc && es_digito != 0; ++i) {
        aux = atoi(argv[i]);
        media += aux;
    }
    if (es_digito == 0) {
        printf("Hubo error. Solo valen numeros\n");
    } else {
        media = media/(argc-1);
        printf("La media es: %lf\n",media);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
es_digito = isdigit(argv[1]);
```

Esa línea tiene dos problemas:

Preguntar directamente por el argumento 2 sin saber si existe es arriesgado y puede hacer que tu programa falle. Eso deberías controlarlo.

El segundo error es que `argv`  es un puntero doble (`char *argv[]`), luego `argv[i]` es un puntero de tipo char. Si quieres comprobar el carácter tienes que añadir un asterisco al código: `es_digito = isdigit(*argv[1]);`

Por otro lado, si te fijas, verás que a `es_digito` únicamente se le asigna valor una vez, luego no estás comprobando si cada parámetro es numérico. Únicamente estás comprobando el primero y tu código asume que el resto serán válidos porque sí.